# SCP command line and PHP exec() not doing the same thing

Tags: php, linux, apache, ssh, scp

When I run this on the command line:

```
scp -i private.ppk -P 22 foo.txt someuser@domain.com:/home/someuser/foo.txt
```

Everything works fine. `foo.txt` gets transferred to the remote server without any problems. I need to run the exact same command from PHP. So, I have the following code:

```
$command = 'scp -i private.ppk -P 22 foo.txt someuser@domain.com:/home/someuser/foo.txt';
exec($command);
```

This doesn't work. The PHP file is being executed in the same directory as `private.ppk`. When I `var_dump` the results of the `exec`, I get a `NULL`.

I'm wondering if this is a permission problem. I know who I am running as on the command line, but I am not sure who is running the script. Could that be the problem? Or is it something completely different?

Comment: Try using the full path to foo.txt

Comment: OK, I did. It was definitely a problem. However, I'm still getting the same results. No file transferred. NULL is the result of `exec`.

Comment: My script is running as `nobody`. Does that cause any problems?

Comment: The script running as `nobody` shouldn't be an issue as far as reading `foo.txt` however, it may be an issue reading the private key file. Try copying the ppk to `/home/nobody/.ssh/private.ppk`. Be sure to `chown` it to the `nobody` user as well.

Comment: More odd problems. First of all, I did a `file_exists` on the private key file. It returns a `TRUE`. But when I put it in `/home/foo/.ssh/private.ppk`, I get a `FALSE`. Notice I had to put it in "foo" ("foo" is a folder that does exist under /home/). I couldn't put it in `/home/nobody/.ssh/` because `nobody` doesn't exist; am I supposed to create it? I know the PHP runs as "nobody" because I echo the results of `whoami` from PHP.

Answer (score 1):

I think it is a permission issue. SSH clients usually refuse to connect unless the permissions have been set such that third parties (such as the user "nobody") can't read the keys.

That said, it is a bit odd that you're using a *.ppk - which is the extension PuTTY keys use - which OpenSSH doesn't support.

That said, my recommendation would be to use [phpseclib's SCP client](http://phpseclib.sourceforge.net/). You can just have the keys as a string in the PHP file itself at that point instead of having to have them live in the filesystem. More info:

https://github.com/phpseclib/phpseclib/blob/master/phpseclib/Net/SCP.php